# Laravel Eloquent Lazy Eager Load Count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm ideally looking for a function like

```
load('relationship')
```

but which loads a count in the same way

```
withCount('relationship')
```

works for eager loading.

I'm thinking it is going to be called `loadCount('relationship')`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`loadCount()` is available since **Laravel 5.8**

```
$post->loadCount('comments');

$post->comments_count;
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_loadCount)

Comment: if someone's method is `myMethod` and trying to load the count, it should be `my_method_count`.

Answer (score 37):

As of Laravel 5.2, this functionality is built-in.

Provided you have a hasMany relationship between Post and Comment, do:

```
<?php

$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

You can even eager load relationships count by default by declaring this in your model:

```
<?php

// Post model

protected $withCount = ['comments'];
```

Comment: This is all true, however I was looking for lazy eager loading ([see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)), i.e. being able to load a count after the model has already been retrieved.

Comment: No the accepted answer is totally right for lazy loading counts

Comment: @shigg Except that it's not lazy loading anything. The count query is performed at the same time as the main query, meaning it's being eager loaded. Which Laravel supports by default as I demonstrated above.

Answer (score 16):

[This solution](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/) works great for me:

Create a new hasOne relationship on the related model and add a raw select to the query for the count. For example, if you want to eager load the number of tasks for a given user, add this to the User Model:

```
public function taskCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Task')
    ->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as count)
    ->groupBy('user_id');
}
```

And then eager load the count like this:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->with('taskCount')->first();
```

And access the count like this:

```
$taskCount = $user->task_count->count;
```

Comment: This is looking really good and the link you provide includes adding a custom Accessor which makes it even simpler.  Just need to confirm that it works with lazy eager loading and we'll be away.

Comment: It would be better if Laravel have this function build in with Eloquent...

Comment: It does. Check my answer.